# Destructor call in a class constructor with a vector

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

I have the following class which simply wraps an array and adds with the constructor some elements to it:

```
class myArray {
public:
    myArray();
    myArray(int a, int b);
    myArray(int a, int b, int c);
    myArray(myArray&& emplace);

    ~myArray();

    int& operator [](int id);

private:
    int *data;
};

myArray::myArray() {
    data = new int[1];
    data[0] = 0;
}

myArray::myArray(int a, int b) {
    data = new int[3];
    data[0] = 0;
    data[1] = a;
    data[2] = b;
}

myArray::myArray(int a, int b, int c) {
    data = new int[4];
    data[0] = 0;
    data[1] = a;
    data[2] = b;
    data[3] = c;
}

myArray::~myArray() {
    std::cout << "Destructor"<<std::endl;
    delete[] data;
}

int& myArray::operator [](int id) {
    return data[id];
}

myArray::myArray(myArray&& emplace) : data(std::move(emplace.data)) {}
```

Furthermore I have a second class which contains a vector of elements of the first class (`myArray`).

```
class Queue {
public:
    Queue();

private:
    std::vector<myArray> _queue;
};

Queue::Queue {
    _queue.reserve(1000);
    for(int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
        for(int b = 0; b < 10; b++)
            for(int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
                        _queue.emplace_back(a,b,c);
}
```

My question here is: Why is the destructor called for the myArray elements at the end of the Queue constructor? The Queue object is still alive in my main program but the destructor of myArray frees the allocated memory and I consequently get a segmentation fault.

Is there a way to avoid the call of the destructor or rather call it not until at the end of the Queue objects lifetime?

Comment: myArray objects are copied into vector and it has double deletion problem.
checkout rule of three

Comment: @billz There's no copying of myArray in the Queue constructor. Probably the Queue is copied somewhere else though.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce it](https://godbolt.org/z/9dFyaT)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your move constructor doesn't set `data` to null on the moved from object so when the moved from object is destructed it will try to free data.

If you have c++14 you can use `std::exchange` to implement this:

```
myArray::myArray(myArray&& emplace)
 : data{std::exchange(emplace.data, nullptr)})
{}
```

Otherwise you need to do:

```
myArray::myArray(myArray&& emplace)
 : data{emplace.data)
{
  emplace.data = nullptr;
}
```

The move constructor will be invoked by `std::vector` as it reallocates to increase its capacity when you call `emplace_back`. Something like the following steps are performed:

1. Allocate new memory to hold the elements
2. Move construct using placement new elements in the new memory from the elements in the previous memory
3. Destruct the elements in the previous memory
4. Deallocate the previous memory

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the segmentation fault!

If I unterstand that correctly the memory of an vector element is allocated and free'd twice? The first time at the end of the Queue constructor and the second at the call of the Queue deconstructor?

Comment: No, you object is constructed when you call `emplace_back` and it is destructed when you erase the element or the vector is destructed. In addition when the vector changes capacity new elements will be created with a copy or move constructor from all the existing elements and all the existing elements will then be destructed.